# Kernel 5.15* and 5.14* fails to suspend

Tags: 20.04, kernel, suspend

As the title suggests, I cannot suspend my laptop using kernel 5.15.* or 5.14*. When trying to suspend, the screen goes blank, but the keyboard backlight still lights up, and the fans are running.

Laptop info:

- Asus ROG M16
- 11th Gen Intel® Core™ i9-11900H @ 2.50GHz × 16
- SK Hynix SSD
- 1x 8GB and 1x 16GB Samsung DDR4 PC4-21300, 2666MHZ
- Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics (TGL GT1)
- Nvidia RTX 3060
- Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
- Kernel 5.15.2

Solutions tried
;

I have downgraded to kernel 5.13.19 and the suspend feature works again, but I cannot install nvidia-driver, either version 460 or 470. So I'm stuck between either having a working Nvidia driver or a suspend feature.

I'm not sure how to provide the log when suspend fails, but hope someone can guide me to debug this. I also added a photo of my BIOS settings, in case the problem lies there.

[image: BIOS settings]

Comment: I'm on a System76 Galago Pro running Pop!_OS 21.04 and suspend stopped working for me between in 5.13.0-7620 (works in 5.13.0-7614)

Comment: It seems that System76 cannot reproduce this problem on the same kernel version that I'm running which makes me think this may be specific to either NVMe or RAM (the only uncommon hardware components). What RAM and NVMe are you running? I'm running an ADATA SX8200NP and 2x 16GB Crucial 3200MHz.

Comment: @curiouser I'm running an SK Hynix SSD, with 1x 8GB and 1x 16GB Samsung DDR4 PC4-21300, 2666MHZ